# Paid translation service for research papers

Tags: software, translations, literature

As a research/lab manager, I am looking for (paid) translation service to translate academic papers. Does anyone know of a good option? In my case I am looking for a German to English translation.

I have tried Google translate as suggested in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/87944/7368), but (as of now, September 2023) it seems to have trouble dealing with old PDFs where the characters are not fully legible.

The service can be paid with research funding, so cost should not be a limitation. I would be OK both with traditional (human) translation or a different paid software service.

Comment: This is a "shopping question" and so, off topic here.

Comment: [Related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90318/do-repositories-of-translated-papers-exist)

Comment: Done translation work for papers in the engineering field - they tried some language specialists but since they did not understand the engineering they made a complete hash of it... So be careful who you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProZ: ProZ (https://www.proz.com/) is a platform that connects you with professional human translators specializing in various fields
Editage: Editage (https://www.editage.com/) offers academic translation services for researchers and authors
Some universities and research institutions have their own translation departments or partnerships with professional translation services. You can inquire within your organization to see if such resources are available.

Freelance Translators:
You can hire freelance translators who specialize in academic content. Platforms like Upwork, Freelancer, or specialized translation websites can help you find experienced freelancers.

AND:
Gengo
ProZ.com
SDL Trados Studio

Comment: ProZ allows translators to bid on a project, to provide their CV, and other features. I believe it is considered best to get someone whose native language is the target language - English in your example.